# SSL Client Authentication Broken in Android 4.0

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have an Android app which uses an SSLSocketFactory to load a pkcs12 certificate and use that certificate to perform SSL Client authentication with my server.  This process worked perfectly on Android 2.1, 2.2, and 2.3, but when I attempt to run this code on a phone or emulator running 4.0 my server does not receive a public key from the request made by my application.

Here is the code I am using to get the HttpClient I use to perform my request

```
private HttpClient getHttpClient(Context context) {
    if(httpClient == null) {
        KeyStore mycert = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        byte[] pkcs12 = persistentStorage.getPKCS12Certificate(context);

        ByteArrayInputStream pkcs12BAIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs12);
        mycert.load(pkcs12BAIS, config.getPassword().toCharArray());

        SSLSocketFactory sockfact = new SSLSocketFactory(mycert, null, null);

        sockfact.setHostnameVerifier(new StrictHostnameVerifier());

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("https",sockfact , config.getPort()));

        BasicHttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpParameters, false);
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParameters, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 3000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 3000);

        ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParameters, registry);
        cm.closeExpiredConnections();
        cm.closeIdleConnections(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, httpParameters);

    }

    return httpClient;
}
```

Comment: Does your application crash, any exception or abnormal from Logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that as of ICS the SSLSocketFactory (or some other part of the system) will no longer properly accept unsigned x509 certificates (which I used to create the pkcs12 cert).  I just had to self sign the certificate and my existing java code worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Note that after Android 3.0 (API Level 11), network operation is restricted on UI thread.  Do you by any chance call network operation on UI thread?

[StrictMode.ThreadPolicy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.html) was introduced since API Level 9 and the default thread policy had been changed since API Level 11, which in short, does not allow network operation (include HttpClient and HttpUrlConnection) get executed on UI thread. if you do this, you get NetworkOnMainThreadException.

It is always recommended to move network operation off the UI thread, for example, using AsyncTask.

Hope this help.

Comment: No, all my network code is run in an AsyncTask but I was not aware of that change...good to know.